# C++: changing output file inside IF statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, file-io

Here I show a snippet of my C++ code which loops over some k values and if k=0 should send the output to one file (`outputk0.txt)`, if k!=0 to another one (`outputnotk0.txt`). I am having a problem with the scope of the `out` ofstream file when compiling. Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
for(int k = 0; k < number_of_l_steps; k++)
  {

    if(k == 0)
      std::ofstream out("outputk0.txt", ios::out);
    else
      std::ofstream out("outputnotk0.txt", ios::out);

    for(int i = 0; i < n_k; i++)
    {
      cout << i << endl;
      double k = exp( log(kmin1) + i*(log(kmax) - log(kmin1))/(n_k-1.));
      for(int j = 0; j < n_z; j++)
      {
         double z = zmin + j*(zmax - zmin)/(n_z-1.);
      //  cout << k << " " << z << endl;
        out << i << " " <<  j <<  " " << cv.U(z,k) << endl;
        //out << i << " " << j << " " << gsl_matrix_get(Gl,i,j) << endl;
      }
    }
    out.close();
  }
```

Comment: Maybe first `std::ofstream out;` before `if` statements and then `out.open("outputk0.txt", ios::out)` and `out.open("outputnotk0.txt", ios::out)`?

Comment: You'll get a compile-time-error complaining about `out` being an undeclared identifier. That is because `out` is scoped to `if condition`.

Comment: @Raindrop7 That's precisely what OP stated via statement "_I am having a problem with the scope of the `out` ofstream file when compiling_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> out;
if(k == 0)
  out = new std::ofstream("outputk0.txt", ios::out);
else
  out = new std::ofstream("outputnotk0.txt", ios::out);
```

You have to write

```
 *out << i << " " <<  j <<  " " << cv.U(z,k) << endl;
```

then of course.

---

Another option, as mentioned in comments, is to use the `open()` function:

```
std::ofstream out;
if(k == 0)
  out.open("outputk0.txt", ios::out);
else
  out.open("outputnotk0.txt", ios::out);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could solve in a couple of ways.
Possible solution #1:

Declare `std::ofstream` at the top of the `if` statement, and call `open` method to open the file.

```
std::ofstream out;
if(k == 0)
  out.open("outputk0.txt", ios::out);
else
  out.open("outputnotk0.txt", ios::out);
```

Possible solution (family) #2:
Use `if-else` for storing the file name in a string, which you use for passing to `std::ofstream` constructor:

1.

```
std::ofstream out(k == 0 ? "outputk0.txt" : "outputnotk0.txt", ios::out);
```

2.

```
std::string fileName;
if (k == 0)
    fileName = "outputk0.txt";
else // more if cases if needed..
    fileName = "outputnotk0.txt";

std::ofstream out(fileName, ios::out); // use fileName.c_str () if not using C++-11.
```

3.

```
std::string fileName;
switch (k)
    {
    case 0:
        fileName = "outputk0.txt";
        break;
    // More cases if needed..
    default:
        fileName = "outputnotk0.txt";
    }

std::ofstream out(fileName, ios::out); // use fileName.c_str () if not using C++-11.
```

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers must be defined at compile-time (a specific type) That is why we cannot create new types at runtime.

In your case you are creating an object "out" scoped to some condition so bear in mind that even the condition succeeds the identifier cannot be used outside of the scope where it was declared.

As an example:

```
if(1) // always true condition
    int a = 0;
std::cout << a; // you get a compile-time error undeclared identifier
```

- The only time you may do such thing is only if you need that variable only inside that scope:

  ```
  if(SomConditionIsTrue){
      int var;
      std::cin >> var;
      std::cout << var;
  }
  ```
- Consider this example:

  ```
  #if(true)
      std::ofstream out("data.txt");
  #endif

  out << "To be written into file"; // now it works

  #if(false)
      std::ofstream out("data.txt");
  #endif

  out << "To be written into file"; // now it doesn't work because the condition fails so no `out` is declared consequently not added by the pre-processor.
  ```

In your case declare an object outside then under some condition initialize it:

```
std::ofstream out("outputk0.txt", ios::out);

for(;;){
   out << "something"; // out is visible here. the compiler looks up and sees it.
}
```